# extract attributes values from an activerecord query object in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-2

In my controller I have a @attach object and when I inspect it, it has values as

```
[#<MessageAddlAttachment id: 80, reminder_id: 112, msg_attachment_file_name: "24.png", msg_attachment_content_type: "image/png", msg_attachment_file_size: 272368, created_at: "2013-10-10 12:04:37", updated_at: "2013-10-10 12:04:37">, #<MessageAddlAttachment id: 81, reminder_id: 112, msg_attachment_file_name: "37.png", msg_attachment_content_type: "image/png", msg_attachment_file_size: 333986, created_at: "2013-10-10 12:04:37", updated_at: "2013-10-10 12:04:37">]
```

So now after some operation I need to create an entry in this MessageAddlAttachment table with different ids. How can I achieve it. I tried dup but it will have same ids. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dup` is your friend in rails 4. it will create a copy but removes the id value:

```
u = User.first
=> #<User id: 1, ...>
u.dup
=> #<User id: nil, ...>
u.dup.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting either rails 3.2 or 3.1, you want to use `dup`. Prior to that, you should use `clone` instead. That will give you new values for the id field; you might want to pay attention to what happens to your created_at and updated_at fields as well.

Another issue to watch out for is if you have any date fields with validations that say they must be after "today's date", they may have been valid when the original record was saved, but not when the new record is saved. How you resolve this will depend on your situation; you might want to disable validations completely while cloning, or adjust the values in the new records.

Comment: I used clone method but how do I avoid created_at and updated_at attributes to be cloned and save it with correct values

Comment: In my situation I wanted the records to have the original created_at values, so that's probably what you're seeing. If you want them updated, you'll probably have to explicitly set .created_at to Time.now and .save the record, which ought to update the .updated_at field for you.